# Stuck on trying to display blog post archives on a custom page template && I can't figure out how to change the URL for each blog post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm making a travel blog from scratch using wordpress and developing my own wordpress theme.

I'm wanting to give 5 different countries their own page that has its own post archive based on which country you are viewing. e.g. if I'm on the Thailand page, it should show all of the Thailand blog posts.

The first bit I'm struggling with is, when I go onto the Thailand page ***".../destinations/thailand"***, it doesn't come up with any posts that belong to the "Thailand" category. but when i navigate to ***".../category/thailand"***, they all show up.

My goal is to make each country's blog posts archive display on the country's page url so it looks something like this ***".../destinations/thailand"***

My other issue is making the URL of each blog post change from ***".../blog-post-1"*** to ***"/destinations.../thailand/blog-post-1"***

I've created include files with the post loop and called the include file in the custom page i've created, the same way that i would with archive.php file.

the posts show when i go to ***".../category/blog"*** but not when i go to ***".../destinations/thailand"***

Comment: So is `destinations` a custom taxonomy and `thailand` a term in that taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to create a custom structure for your travel blog where each country has its own page displaying blog posts related to that country. Let's address the issues you're facing.

#### 1. Displaying Country-Specific Blog Posts:

##### 1.1. Check the Category Slug:

Ensure that the category slug for Thailand is "thailand" and not something else. You can do this by going to "Posts" in your WordPress dashboard, editing a post assigned to the Thailand category, and checking the category section to verify the slug.

##### 1.2. Use the Category Template:

WordPress automatically looks for a template file based on the category when viewing a category page. Make sure you have a template file named `category-thailand.php` in your theme directory. This template file will be used when viewing the category page for Thailand.

Here's a basic example of what `category-thailand.php` might look like:

```php
<?php
get_header();

echo '<h1>Thailand Posts</h1>';

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part('content', 'archive'); // Use your post loop include file
    endwhile;
else :
    echo '<p>No posts found</p>';
endif;

get_footer();
?>
```

Make sure to replace `'content', 'archive'` with the actual names of your include file.

#### 2. Changing Blog Post URLs:

##### 2.1. Permalinks Structure:

To achieve the desired URL structure, you'll need to update your permalink settings. Go to "Settings" > "Permalinks" in the WordPress dashboard. Choose the "Custom Structure" option and set it to:

```
/destinations/%category%/%postname%/
```

[Check screenshots for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0FuX.png)

##### 2.2. Update Category Links:

When displaying links to the Thailand category, ensure you're using `get_category_link` with the correct category ID or slug:

```php
$category_link = get_category_link(get_cat_ID('thailand'));
echo '<a href="' . esc_url($category_link) . '">Thailand</a>';
```

Make sure to adjust these steps based on your specific theme structure and requirements. If you're still facing issues, consider sharing more details about your theme structure or the code you're using, and I can provide more targeted assistance.